# toolbar back arrow doesn't work

Tags: android, toolbar

I create other activity and hope use toolbar back arrow to return main activity, but under code doesn't work, please help me.

```
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.setting);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);  
    mToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                System.out.println("??");
                finish();
                return true;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try This Method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:


            return true;

        }
            return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The Toolbar has a method for this, `setNavigationOnClickListener`. It allows you to listen for click events on the back arrow. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) is the documentation if you want to read more about the Toolbar.

```
 mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("??");
            finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```